# bash scripting..copying files without overwriting

Tags: bash

I would like to know if it is possible to copy/move files to a destination based on the origin name.

Basically, I have a /mail folder, which has several subfolders such as cur and new etc. I then have an extracted backup in /mail/home/username that is a duplicate. mv -f will not work, as I do not have permission to overwrite the directories, but only the files within.

I get errors such as mv: cannot overwrite directory `/home/username/mail/username.com'

What I want to do is for each file in the directory username.com, move it to the folder of the same name in /mail. There could be any number of folders in place of username.com, with seperate sub sirectories of their own.

What is the best way to do this?

I have to do it this way as due to circumstances I only have access to my host with ftp and bash via php.

edit: clarification

I think I need to clarify what happened. I am on a shared host, and apparently do not have write access to the directories themselves. At least the main ones such as mail and public_html. I made a backup of ~/mail with tar, but when trying to extract it extracted to ~/mail/home/mail etc, as I forgot about the full path. Now, I cannot simply untar because the path is wrong, and I cannot mv -f because I only have write access to files, not directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For copying, you should consider using `cpio` in 'pass' mode (`-p`):

```
cd /mail; find . -type f | cpio -pvdmB /home/username/mail
```

The `-v` is for verbose; `-d` creates directories as necessary; `-m` preserves the modification times on the files; `-B` means use a larger block size, and may be irrelevant here (it used to make a difference when messing with tape devices).  Omitted from this list is the `-u` flag that does unconditional copying, overwriting pre-existing files in target area.  The `cd` command ensures that the path names are correct; if you just did:

```
find /mail -type f | cpio -pvdmB /home/username
```

you would achieve the same result, but only by coincidence - because the sub-directory under `/home/username` was the same as the absolute pathname of the original.  If you needed to do:

```
find /var/spool/mail -type f | cpio -pvdmB /home/username/mail
```

then the copied files would be found under `/home/username/mail/var/spool/mail`, which is unlikely to be what you had in mind.

You can achieve a similar effect with (GNU) `tar`:

```
(cd /mail; tar -cf - . ) | (cd /home/username/mail; tar -xf - )
```

This copies directories, not just files.  To do that, you need GNU-only facilities:

```
(cd /mail; find . -type f | tar -cf - -F - ) | (cd /home/username/mail; tar -xf - )
```

The first solo dash means 'write to stdout'; the second means 'read from stdin'; the '-F' option means 'read the file names to copy from the named file'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on what it is that you want to do, but you could try the following:

```
for file in /mail/*; do
    mv -f $file /home/username/mail/$(basename $file)
done
```

This will move every file and subdirectory in /mail from there into /home/username/mail.

Comment: I think that is the reverse of what I want to do? I extracted a mail archive into the mail folder, but it made a subdirectory under mail which I can now not restore, because I cannot overwrite the original directories

Answer (score 0):

Is using `tar` an option? You could `tar` up the directory, and extract it under `/mail/` (for I am assuming that is what you want roughly) with `tar` overwriting existing files and directories.

Comment: That is what I tried, the problem is I can only overwrite files, not directories

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what it is exactly that you want to do. But you should be able to use the approach of Adam's solution and redirect the errors to a file.

```
for file in /mail/*; do
    mv -f $file /home/username/mail/$(basename $file) 2> /tmp/mailbackup.username.errors
done
```

DIrectories will not be overwritten and you can check the file so that it only contaions errors you anticipate.

Comment: The problem is that I can not overwrite directories, only files, and my mail archive is currently in a subdirectoy of mail. restoring it seems impossible using normal tools.

Comment: Yes, but I think if you try something like what I suggest you'll get all the files moved and any error messages from npt being able to overwrite directories will be redirected to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you untar it again? The -P option to *tar* will not strip leading "/", so the absolute pathnames will be respected.  From your edit, it sounds like this'll fix it.

Comment: I tried that, it gives the error: tar: /home/username/mail: Not found in archive after trying with tar xzvfP ~/new/moremail.tgz ~/mail

Comment: Er, that means you only want the item "~/mail" in the archive to be extracted.

Comment: I used -P in the root directory, and /mail is also in the root directory. It just extracted the folder /home/username/mail, I cannot get it to extract just the mail folder..

Answer (score 0):

Even with your clarification I'm still having a problem understanding exactly what you're doing. However, any chance you can use rsync? The src and dest hosts can be the same host for rsync. As I recall, you can tell rsync to only update files that already exist in the destination area (--existing) and also to ignore directory changes (--omit-dir-times).

Again, I'm not quite understanding your needs here, but rsync is very flexible in backing up files and directories.

Good luck.

Comment: Aah, I see you only have access to ftp and bash. Well, nevermind I guess.